# Generating Log for mkdir command in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, bigdata

Is there any means to generate a success/failure log for a **hadoop fs -mkdir** command. May be for all set of hadoop shell commands.

Comment: You can try reading return code from this command using bash

Comment: But is that possible to get return code from the hadoop shell? Possibly a wrong doubt, but excuse me for my infamiliarity with the shell operations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
hadoop fs -mkdir /foo
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
#action
fi
```

Made slight syntax change. Thanks, It helped. But can me have some log for this purpose by setting some property? That means, for each directory made on hdfs through shell or through java api, can we have some log being recorded?

Answer (score 1):

All hadoop shell commands will return 0 on success. You should just check for this - it's the most reliable way.

```
hadoop dfs -mkdir /foo
if [ $? eq 0]
#success, do something
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

The fs shell command does not have any such command. If you're using the java api, the FileSystem.mkdirs method also returns a result code along with a exception on failure.

Do you just want to print a log on failure or success? In that case, the best way is to print out whatever you want from within your script after checking the return code.